# How to create missing volume tag in lambda python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to create a tag on an Amazon EBS Volume, but only if the tag doesn't exist. Everything else is working on my code but this part is somehow not working. I want this Lambda function to create a tag if the value doesn't match with my given value. Another condition is if the tag doesn't exist then create a tag. So my first condition is working but not the second one. If the tag doesn't exist, I get an error saying (Please see the attached) this method is invalid. I am using `!=` and Also, I used `if not in tag['Key'] == 'Tech.BackUp.Retention.Days'`. This line also gives me an error.

**Edited:**

- If I don't have the `Tech.Backup.Retention.Days` tag then I want to create a tag: `Tech.Backup.Retention.Days`. The Value doesn't matter I can work on that.
- It just my condition is not working properly. For example I have listed of 3 volumes and each one of them contain certain type of tags. Some of them with `Tech.Backup.Retention.Days` and some of them doesn't have it. Which ever the one doesn't have it, I want to create it.

Another point: [Lambda function to check if specific tag do NOT exists-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50823252/lambda-function-to-check-if-specific-tag-do-not-exists-python)

Here is the similar question I have found but this method doesn't even work. Trust me I have been researching for a week and not able to solve it. I am new to lambda may be i am missing out some tricks.

**Edited 2ndV**

What I will be doing here is: If I find a Backup tag then check  the value (30), If the value is 30 then delete the volume, If the value is not 30 then update the value to 30. Note: I coudn't find how to update the value so everytime the value doesn't match I create a new tag with given value. Last, If the tag doesn't even exist then create a new tag.

Problem: After I added your coded now if the tag doesn't exist then it is creating a new tag but if the tag exist and the value match then it is not deleting.

Here is my whole code:

```
TAG1 = 'Tech.BackUp.Retention.Days'
TAG2 = 'Tech.Backup.Time.HourOfDay'
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name='us-east-2')
volume_list = ['1111']
for volume in volume_list:
    try:
        tag1_value = ([tag['Value'] for tag in volume.tags if tag['Key'] == TAG1] or [None])[0]
        tag2_value = ([tag['Value'] for tag in volume.tags if tag['Key'] == TAG2] or [None])[0]

        #first tag
        if  tag1_value == '30':
            print("Exist")
        else:
            delV.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key':TAG1, 'Value': '30'}])
            delV.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key':TAG2, 'Value': '01'}])
            break
        #second tag
        if tag2_value == '01':
            print("delete")
    except ClientError as e:
        continue
```

[Picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pw3m.png)

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide the exact logic (in words) that you would like to apply? For example "If a xyz tag does not exist, create it with a value of 20."

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have edited the question. Please let me know if you need anything else or if you have more questions.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that adds the tag if is not already present:

```py
import boto3

TAG_NAME = 'Tech.BackUp.Retention.Days'

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')

volumes = ec2_resource.volumes.all()
for volume in volumes:
    # If there are no tags named TAG_NAME:
    if not any(tag['Key'] for tag in volume.tags if tag['Key'] == TAG_NAME):
        # Add the tag
        print('Adding tag to', volume.id)
        volume.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key':TAG_NAME, 'Value': '20'}])
```

Basically, it looks at all the Keys of the tags and checks whether the desired tag is *not* present. If so, it adds the tag.

If might look a bit strange, but it's more Pythonesque to use the list comprehension.

---

Based on your updated requirements:

```py
import boto3

TAG1 = 'Tech.BackUp.Retention.Days'
TAG2 = 'Tech.BackUp.Time.HourOfDay'

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')

volumes_list = ['vol-1234']
for volume in volumes_list:

    # Get value of TAG1
    tag1_value = ([tag['Value'] for tag in volume.tags if tag['Key'] == TAG1] or [None])[0]

    if tag1_value == '30':
        # Delete the volume
        volume.delete()
    else:
        volume.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key':TAG1, 'Value': '30'}])
        volume.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key':TAG2, 'Value': '01'}])
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I have edited again and included my whole code. and also explained what I am trying to do exactly. See the edited 2nv

Comment: Added another answer for your updated requirements. Please note that my suggested code does not require a loop through the tags (`for tag in vtag.tags`).

Comment: I have to change my whole code if i do it that way right and also I was checking for the second tag value so I am working on it if i get an error, will let you know. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: It doesn't work. That's the error : tag1_Value is not working properly 
- Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "'str' object has no attribute 'tags'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 12, in lambda_handler\n    tag1_value = ([tag['Value'] for tag in delV.tags if tag['Key'] == TAG1] or [None])[0]\n"
  ]
}

Comment: The error message is saying that your `delV` variable is a string, not a volume. I think you should be using `vtag.tags`, not `delV.tags`. I would recommending more descriptive variable names to avoid potential errors like this (eg `for volume in volumes_list:`).

Comment: I have uploaded the new code and still the same error. Please see the code to my original question.

Comment: Your `delV.create_tags()` should be `volume.create_tags()`. If that doesn't fix it, please provide the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Above logic is working. The only issue is you have to include `[]`, so that it accepts an empty value as well (for **TypeError**).

If not, any `(tag['Key'] for tag in volume.tags` **or []** `if tag['Key'] == TAG_NAME):`.